# Как отправить проект Андроид студио на GitHub?

Tags: android-studio, github

У меня есть пустой репозиторий как можно туда поместить проект из андроид студио?

Comment: Установить GitHub Desktop и через него. Вроде из командной строки сейчас не работает

Comment: Задай remote, потом commit и всё это push. В чём именно сложность?

Answer (score 1):

Пользоваться автоматическими средствами не рекомендую, надо уметь владеть с git.

Если проект маленький то можно в ручную через саму платформу github. Но если большой тогда -

В android studio, заходишь в -  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И поочериди прописываешь команды

1 - git init

2 - git add .

3 - git commit -m "first commit"

4 - git branch -M main

5 - git remote add origin здесь ссылка на твой репозиторий

6 - git push -u origin main

Что бы понять что значат эти команды лучше почитай доки.

Еще когда создал репозиторий уже есть маленькая дока как выкладывать проект -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я согласен, что имеет смысл уметь пользоваться cmd гитом. Но почему "Пользоваться автоматическими средствами не рекомендую"? Ведь это ускоряет процесс и уменьшает вероятность ошибок.

Answer (score 0):

Андроид студио умеешь, а поиск не умеешь?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно, у тебя эта менюшка называется VCS.